# How to retrieve the latest version of a record in GAE's high replication datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have created a REST service for syncing data from iPhones to our GAE.
In a few situations we get double entries for the same day. I believe I have made a mistake in the design of the `Record` class and would like to double check if my assumption and possible solution is correct before I attempt any data migration.

First I go through all incoming json_records, if it finds count == 1, then that means there is an existing entry that needs to be updated (This is where it goes **sometimes** wrong!!!). Then it checks the timestamp and would only update it if the incoming timestamp is greater, otherwise it ignores it.

```
for json_record in json_records:
    recordsdb = Record.query(Record.user == user.key, Record.record_date == date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']))
         if recordsdb.count() == 1:
             rec = recordsdb.fetch(1)[0]
             if rec.timestamp < json_record['timestamp']:
                  ....
                  rec.put()

         elif recordsdb.count() == 0:
             new_record = Record(user=user.key, 
                                    record_date = date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']), 
                                    notes = json_record['notes'], 
                                    timestamp = json_record['timestamp'])
             new_record.put()
```

If I am not wrong, this way of querying an object, provides no gurantee that it is the latest version.

```
recordsdb = Record.query(Record.user == user.key, Record.record_date == date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']))
```

I believe the only way GAE/Highreplication Datastore can make sure that you have the latest data in front of you is if you retrieve it by a key.

Hence, if this assumption is correct, I should have saved my records with a date string as the key in first place.

```
jsondate = date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']
new_record = Record(id = jsondate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    user=user.key, 
                    record_date = jsondate), 
                    notes = json_record['notes'], 
                    timestamp = json_record['timestamp'])
new_record.put()
```

and when I have to query to see if the record already exists, I would get it by its key like this:

```
jsondate = date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']
record = ndb.Key('Record', jsondate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).get()
```

Now if record is null then I have to create a new record.
if record != null then I have to update it.

Is my assumption and solution correct?
How can I migrate this data with date-string as their key?

**UPDATE**

I just realised another mistake I made. I can't set the record to its date-string.  Because each user can have a record for a day, which causes duplication for the key.

I believe the only way to solve that is through `ancestor/parent`, which I am still trying to get my head around it.

**UPDATE 2:**

Trying to see if I understand Patrick's solution here. If it doesn't make sense, or there is a better way, please correct me.

I would add a `is_fixed` flag to the existing model:

```
class Record(ndb.Model)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    is_fixed = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    ...
```

Then I would query for the existing records via a cursor and delete them afterwards:

```
q = Record.query()
q_forward = q.order(Record.key)
cursor = None

while True:
   records, cursor, more = q_forward.fetch_page(100)
   if not records:
      break;
   for record in records:
       new_record = Record(parent=user.key, ... )
       new_record.is_fixed = True
       new_record.put()

//now delete the old ones, I wonder if this would be an issue:
for old in Record.query()
   if not old.is_fixed:
      old.delete()
```

Comment: For the null part and the create use get_or_insert. Other than that looks good.

Comment: This [follow-on question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665098/duplicate-entries-in-high-replication-datastore) reports that the solution was applpied but did not really solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query is always per user, I would recommend having the User be a ancestor of the user.

As you mentioned, the issue that you are hitting is a result of eventual consistency -- your query is not guaranteed to have the most up to date results. With an ancestor query, the results will be [strongly consistent](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

One important piece to watch out for is that within an entity group (a single ancestor), you are limited to 1 update per second. Since you only have one record per user, this seems like it shouldn't be a problem.

Your code is actually already all setup to user ancestors:

```
new_record = Record(parent=user.key, # Here we say that the ancestor of the record is the user
                    record_date =date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']), 
                    notes = json_record['notes'], 
                    timestamp = json_record['timestamp'])
```

And then now you can actually use a strongly consistent query:

```
Record.query(ancestor == user.key, Record.record_date == date_parser.parse(json_record['record_date']))
```

However, you are going to have the same problems with changing the id of existing Records. Adding an ancestor to an entity is effectively changing it's key to have the ancestor as a prefix. In order to do this, you'll have to go through all your records and create new ones with their user as an ancestor. You can probably either do this using a query to grab results in batches (using [cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors) to step forward) or if you have a lot of data it may be worthwhile to explore the [MapReduce library](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Its all very clear to me but one thing. We have 2721 records, so maybe cursors will do the job. Please have a look at `Update 2` and tell me if you think thats a correct way to handle it? your help is really appreciated

Comment: You probably can't get through all the records in a single response time, so you'll probably want to do it in stages, saving the cursors between requests. Depending on how you are using the records you may also want to just leave the existing ones there -- if you only use an ancestor query from now on that would be ok. It is very possible that your query over all the records won't get everything due to eventual consistency. You should make sure that all records have been updated before deleting any old ones. See this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema